# Drag and Drop override event for Outlook Item c#

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, outlook, outlook-addin

I searched all over for this thing but no luck yet.
I have an add-in (for outlook) which performs several operations on the Outlook Items(Appointment Item, task).
I just want to override the event when you drag a file onto the body of item and it gets displayed on the body of the item. I just want that item to be attached (& store it at a dir of my choice).
How do I link the event ??
I found one event though.

but in the example,  there is a form always. I don't have a specific form as it's an add-in :(

```
private void Body_DragDrop(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        // Ensure that the list item index is contained in the data. 
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
        {

            Object item = (object)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));

            // Perform drag-and-drop, depending upon the effect. 
            if (e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Copy ||
                e.Effect == DragDropEffects.Move)
            {

                // Insert the item. 
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("there");

            }
        }
    }
```

I found the rest of the details but I am unable to find the event to override.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

for info :
I already gone through these links: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807463/get-body-from-outlook-email-dragndrop/7840474#7840474), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807463/get-body-from-outlook-email-dragndrop), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18741948/net-drag-and-drop-outlook-dragdropeffects-copy) .

EDIT:

My code of adding the appointment is :

```
public bool getAppointments(IList<IAppointmentData> list)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorer expl =  outlookApp.ActiveExplorer();

            try
            {
                if (list.Count != 0)
                {
                    deleteExisting();
                    foreach (IAppointmentData appointmentData in list)
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._AppointmentItem appt = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)
                            outlookApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
                        appt = setMeetingDetails(appt, appointmentData);

                        appt.Recipients.ResolveAll();
                        appt.Save();
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

I need some mechanism to attach the event listed above to the appointment item body when someone drops a file into the body.
How do I do it?

Comment: Maybe you can post the Outlook addin code you have as a point of reference?  The code you posted (a standard drag drop handler) is not the issue here.  You're trying to find out how to attach that to an Outlook addin.

Comment: I am trying to override the the drag and drop event , that's it. is it possible?? I have the normal code of adding the appointment through the code. i will edit my post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no officially supported API to do that. I can only think of dropping down to the Windows API level: you can find the window handle of the editor control, then install your own drag/drop handler using RegisterDragDrop(). Not sure if you can do that in C#... It is definitely doable in C++ or Delphi.

Comment: ok, Thank you so much for the reply. I guess I have to try something different then, maybe attaching the file using standard file open dialog box.