# TextBox with non editable words (tags)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls, .net-4.5

I'm trying to build template editing module for my email sending application.
Right now it looks like this:

[image]

On right I have list of available variables that are replaced to correct values when I send email.

Right now I'm adding words from list on right when I double click o list item:

```
private void variablesLB_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var insert = variablesLB.SelectedItem.ToString();
        var index = templateContentTB.SelectionStart;
        templateContentTB.Text = templateContentTB.Text.Insert(index, insert);
        templateContentTB.SelectionStart = index + insert.Length;
        templateContentTB.Focus();
    }
```

All this works fine, but I can't prevent user from changing keywords manually, so he can place cursor inside `«Email»` and change it to `«Emaail»`

For example in crystal reports after placing database field in text field I was able to select whole name as one and by pressing backspace I could remove whole name.

I know that this functionality isn't build in inside WinForms TextBox and I couldn't find any components that would do that, so I decided to ask here, maybe someone needed same functionality or could guide me how to do this.

Summing up I need to be able to add tag inside text in textbox and textbox should treat this tag as whole - it should be selectable, movable and user should be able to delete it but not edit.

Comment: I dont know what control you are using to display Name, Surname, Email etc. but isnt there a `IsReadOnly` flag, which you can set to `True`?

Comment: @user3596113 sorry if I described something wrong, but when clicking on list on right (listbox) I'm adding text to textbox, this part works fine, I want to have non editable words inside textbox.

Comment: First thought is: use `RichTextBox` and some custom object (image?) for tags. Other possibility is to *highlight* tags as text changed (also `RichTextBox`) so that user see if he *destroy* something. As the user is allowed to edit text, maybe you will show him a **complete** text? Where `<Name>` is already substituted with e.g. `John`?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/789293/Creating-a-Tagging-System-using-ASP-net-implementi

Comment: its usually pretty hard to keep users from shooting themselves in the head.  when they are done provide a Preview type function where the tokens are replaced.  More or less how VS does not prevent you from typing `Tostring` in place of `ToString()` but wont do much with it.

Comment: @husnain_sys I'm looking for WinFOrms solution

Comment: @Plutonix You are right, preview works fine for now, but I would like to add feature I'm describing, CrystalReports has this. Besides I always try to follow one rule: never trust enduser :)

Comment: @Sinatr I have preview functionality that shows complete text.

Comment: See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4544/Insert-Plain-Text-and-Images-into-RichTextBox-at-R) of how to insert smiles into `RichTextBox`. Your tags are *smiles*.

Comment: you could write dozens of lines of code to see if the current char typed is between the start and stop tokens.  Or even without a preview, just parse the text and see if there are any tokens left over afterwards.  If so, "This email contains illegal tokens".

Comment: @Plutonix good idea, I'll add this validation to `Save` button, but then user could add one extra character into tag, so I must search for all tags in text and check if they are on my list.

Comment: @Sinatr thanks for link, but I can't imagine this working in my case. List on right will be dynamic, so I would need to have image for each tag

Comment: I have an app that allows the user to define a "script" in much the same way.  I just do not save if it cannot be parsed completely because it is not legal and if I only save clean, valid scripts, the code doesnt have to be so defensive when using it.

Comment: Since the Textbox is an old and weary beast and since it only contains Text I doubt that a solution better than checking after the fact can be done. One could use timed editing, ie have a timer which gets restarted during each edit and when it finally reaches its Tick after maybe 2 seconds it will do the checks and tell the user about any invalid item; it could even offer to repair.

Comment: - As for the idea with a RTBox: I would have frowned upon it, had I not written just such a thing last week. See [here, the updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025923/how-to-dragdrop-outlook-mail-into-richtextbox/28035088#28035088) for a post that uses a mail icon inserted in a RTB as an immutable token. You could use a few text images for the same purpose..

Answer (score 0):

Using RichTextBox you can achieve what you want.

Basically what the code below does is look for the prefix and suffix search for the string between them, in the collection of variables if the string is found the whole tag string will be selected.

The end result is whenever the user selects a part of your tag it will automatically select all the text between the prefix and suffix.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public const char Prefix = '<';
    public const char Suffix = '>';
    private readonly List<string> _tags = new List<string> {"email"};

    public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int startOfVar = 0;
        int endOfVar = -1;

        for (int i = richTextBox1.SelectionStart - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (richTextBox1.Text[i] == Suffix)
                return;
            if (richTextBox1.Text[i] == Prefix)
            {
                startOfVar = i + 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = startOfVar; i < richTextBox1.TextLength; i++)
        {
            if (richTextBox1.Text[i] == Suffix)
            {
                endOfVar = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (startOfVar < endOfVar)
        {
            var varString = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(startOfVar, endOfVar - startOfVar);

            if (_tags.Contains(varString))
            {
                richTextBox1.Select(startOfVar - 1, endOfVar - startOfVar + 2);
            }
        }
    }    

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(Prefix + _tags[0] + Suffix);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll check that right away :) ANd what about deleting? When I place cursor after tag and press backspace or befor and press delete?

Comment: With the current code it won't delete it. But you can change it to behave the way you want. There are probably some other flaws with the code, but it's nothing that is hard to overcome.