# is it possible to drop in Vaadin from another standalone app?

Tags: drag-and-drop, vaadin

Is it possible to drag-n-drop in Vaadin from another standalone app?

We are trying to drag-n-drop from Outlook an email into our Vaadin app.
Could we accept drag-n-drop events from other app? Not files from the system but some other app?

Comment: As long as the drag source supports it, then yes.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295522/drag-and-drop-outlook-message-into-browser